# How can JavaScript code be added before the closing HTML body tag?

Tags: plugins, code

how can i Add the code to my site before the `</body>` closing tag?

code is

```
<script> (function(w,d,u){ var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/60000|0); var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insert
...
```

Answer (score 1):

With WordPress, JavaScript cannot be output directly to the browser from PHP. You must use WordPress functions like [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) (please read the [Notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes) from the documentation for details) from within an action hook handler for [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/).

WordPress documentation for wp_enqueue_scripts says:

> `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use when enqueuing scripts and styles that are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is **used for enqueuing both scripts and styles**.

To put the script before the end `</body>` tag use the **$args** parameter of the **wp_enqueue_script** function by setting the **in_footer** property to *true*. For example:

```
/**
 * ... enqueue plugin scripts.
 */
function load_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'script-handle-name',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/script.js',
        array(), // Dependencies. Array of script handles for other scripts this script depends on.
        '1.0.0', // Version number.
        array(
            'strategy'  => 'defer'
            'in_footer' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_plugin_scripts' );
```

For some background and another example, see my answer to this Stack Overflow question: [How to include .js in html from wordpress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77550207#77550497).

Answer (score 1):

You can add JavaScript with the help of PHP to the footer with the [`wp_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/) hook.

```php
function customjsscript(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
YOUR SCRIPT
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'customjsscript');
```